# Monkey patching a fetch call using unusual Javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, fetch, monkeypatching

I managed to monkey patch fetch calls of the more common type. But one tool I use makes fetch requests that my code is blind to. I found a fetch call like this which I do not completely understand how it works and how I could monkey patch it to intercept the URL:

await (0, r.Jl)("fetch")(i.toString(),{...});

I understand how await works but the syntax above baffles me. Instead of ... I have a bunch of options for the fetch call.

Thanks,

Alban

r.Jl seems to be a function. I tried to replicate the code above by putting it into an anonymous async function and replaced r.Jl with am empty synchronous anonymous function, and no options object for the second parameter of the fetch call. That gave me a syntax error.